# Inverse of an operator in different spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ and $Z$ be Banach spaces such that $X \hookrightarrow Z$ (i.e. the embedding is continuous). Suppose we have a linear operator $T\in \mathcal{L}(X)$ such that $\Vert T\Vert_{\mathcal{L}(X)}<1$. This estimate ensure that $(I-T)^{-1}\in \mathcal{L}(X)$. Now, since the embedding $X \hookrightarrow Z$ is continuous, one can deduce that $T\in \mathcal{L}(X,Z)$ and $\Vert T\Vert_{\mathcal{L}(X,Z)}<1$. Is it true that $(I-T)^{-1}\in \mathcal{L}(Z,X)$? Thank you for help.

Comment: I don't think $I$ is well defined here.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: Is the embedding isometric? Otherwise I don't think $\|T\|_{\mathcal{L}(X,Z)}<1$ necessarily holds.

Comment: Since the embedding is continuous, we have $\Vert x\Vert_Z\leq \Vert x\Vert_X$, thus $\Vert Tx\Vert_Z\leq \Vert Tx\Vert_X \leq \Vert x \Vert_X$. The embedding is not supposed to be isometric.

Comment: That's not what continuous means, if $i: X\to Z$ is continuous, there's a $c\geq 0$ such that $\|i(x) \| \leq c \|x\|$. The constant $c$ isn't necessarily $1$.

Comment: Ok,sorry  that's correct, but in my case i have $c=1$.

Comment: No problem, I'll think about the question. Although I'm not sure how to approach it, because I've only seen proofs of the invertibility of $(I-T)$ in $\mathcal{L}(X)$ using von Neumann series and I don't see how to generalise such an argument.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I don't think it can be right, what if you took $T = \frac{1}{2}I$. Then that would imply that $i - i \circ T = \frac{1}{2} i$ is invertible. This in turn implies that $i:X \to Z$ is invertible, which is not always the case.